# inspect.getsourcelines new failure: TypeError: is a built-in class

Tags: python

I update to Python 3.8 and now this doesn't work anymore:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.epochs = 30

        self._code = None

    def save_code(self):
        import inspect
        self._code = ''.join(inspect.getsourcelines(self.__class__)[0])
a = A()
a.save_code()
```

Gives this error

`TypeError: <class '__main__.A'> is a built-in class`

Used to work normally before. I understand that this type of error should only be raised if you're referecing a source code that is written in C, not in Python, but this is not C API!